# SP2010 workflow update a form from a task

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm trying to create a workflow that starts when a drop down on a form is set to 'submitted'. This then creates a task in the task list. When the task is completed I want to then update another field on the form to tick a checkbox to say it has been completed.

When I'm designing the workflow I cant figure out how to reference the form from the task list to update the check box. I think I need some way of specifying an ID number to identify which form in the form library I need to update.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to start a workflow from a drop down in your form?

Comment: Yes the workflow starts and a task is created and email sent, the bit i cant do is complete the task and for that to update the form